# delphi convert byte of array to bitmap

Tags: arrays, delphi, bitmap, delphi-7

How to convert byte of array into tbitmap using delphi 7, the array contain png header from memory.

```
bits[0]:= $9E;
bits[1]:= $20;
bits[2]:= $00;
bits[3]:= $00;
bits[4]:= $70;
bits[5]:= $AD;
bits[6]:= $BD;
bits[7]:= $1A;
```

I'm trying using tmemorystream to store the array into bitmap and using PNGImage from Gustav Daud to assign bitmap, but not luck.

```
uses .., PNGImage;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  png      : TPNGObject;
  stream   : TMemoryStream;
  bits     : array[0..7] of byte;
begin
  bits[0]:= $9E;
  bits[1]:= $20;
  bits[2]:= $00;
  bits[3]:= $00;
  bits[4]:= $B8;
  bits[5]:= $EE;
  bits[6]:= $C4;
  bits[7]:= $1A;

  png:= TPNGObject.Create;
  try
    stream:= TMemoryStream.Create;
    try
      stream.Write(bits[0], sizeOf(bits));
      stream.Position:= 0;

      png.LoadFromStream(stream);
    finally
      stream.Free;
      JvImage1.Picture.Assign(png);
    end;
  finally
    png.Free;
  end;
end;
```

This give me stream error, is there any proper write about writing array byte to memorystream?

Thanks,

Comment: You are not dealing with a BMP image, so DO NOT load your bytes into a `TBitmap` object.  Get rid of your `bitm` variable. Also, your array has 9 bytes in ot, but you are only populating 8 bytes. If you want an 8-byte array, you array needs to be declared as `[0..7]` instead of `[0..8]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`TJvImage.Picture` is a standard `TPicture`, which means its `Bitmap` property is a standard `TBitmap`. You **cannot** load a PNG image into a `TBitmap` in VCL (you can in FireMonkey, which Delphi 7 does not support).  You need to use a suitable third-party `TGraphic`-derived class for PNG images (Delphi 7 does not natively support PNGs, that was added in a later version), eg:

```
uses
  ..., PngImage;

var
  Png: TPngObject;
try
  Png := TPngObject;
  try
    stream := TMemoryStream.create;
    try
      stream.Write(bits[0], sizeof(bits));
      stream.Position:= 0;
      Png.LoadFromStream(stream);
    finally
      stream.Free;
    end;
    JvImage1.Picture.Assign(Png);
  finally
    Png.free;
  end;
end;
```

[Delphi 7, load PNG to TImage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6237711/delphi-7-load-png-to-timage)

---

**Update**: However, that being said, the bytes you have shown are NOT a valid PNG graphic header to begin with.  A PNG *always* starts with the following [8-byte signature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#File_header):

```
89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A
```

The bytes do not represent any PNG [data chunk header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#.22Chunks.22_within_the_file), either (in case you are accidentally skipping past a PNG header).

In fact, the bytes you have shown do not appear to represent any commonly-used graphic format.  So you are likely misinterpreting the memory you are trying to examine.

Comment: Regarding using TPngObject from Gustavo Daud, give me new exception EPnginvalidheader is not valid PNG. I'm sure the byte array is png header from memory address of [base_address]+0x28 is 16 array of  byte "9E 20 00 00 B8 EE C4 1A F4 9E 01 00 68 59 BF 1A"

Comment: Is it possible added the 4 bytes PNG Header in first of array, am sure array in address is correct position. I'm using hex memory editor to change the value, seems image changed too.

Comment: @ahrie: The bytes you have shown DO NOT belong to a PNG header. The first **8 bytes** of a PNG are always `89 50 4E 47 0D 0A 1A 0A` (see [Portable Network Graphics, File header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#File_header)). And the bytes do not belong to any PNG [data chunk header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics#.22Chunks.22_within_the_file), either.

Comment: @ahrie: Whatever you *think* you are examining in memory is not a PNG (unless you are skipping past all of the PNG header/chunk info that would tell you what the bytes represent).  What does `base_address` actually point at, and why are you looking at `+0x28` bytes into it? What are you really trying to accomplish? It sounds like you are trying to peer into another process's data, is that right?

Comment: I'm currently want to read image in game, the game using PNG to create avatar. I'm looking other tools game can read those image, but seems not in delphi its c++. Using CE to search the image address, and found [[[[[[base_address]+00376164]+0x28]+0x28]+0x00]+0x6C] as image static address. Changed value to other avatar value seems successful, am using tlhelp32 unit to read process

Comment: What is CE? `[[[[[[base_address]+00376164]+0x28]+0x28]+0x00]+0x6C]` is not even remotely close to being the same memory address as `[base_address]+0x28`, so you are clearly reading the PNG bytes from the wrong memory address to begin with.  How is your Delphi code obtaining the memory address it is reading the bytes from?  Are you hard-coding it, or what?

Comment: Cheat Engine, sorry i'm not complete write all the offset. So i want to fill those array to image, any proper idea? Yup, using array of byte readprocessmemory(PidHandle,pointer(Address),arraybits,Bits,count);

Comment: @ahrie: You still haven't explained how exactly your Delphi code is obtaining the `Address` value (or `count`, for that matter). Maybe the PNG is at a different memory address each time the app is run. Are you accounting for that? And where exactly is the PNG really coming from?  Is it being loaded from a file, or from resources? I seriously doubt it is hard-coded in fixed memory, most apps/games don't do that. If the PNG is a file, you can just grab the file. If the PNG is in a resource, you can access the resource directly (see `FindResource()`/`LoadResource()`/`LockResource()`).

Comment: @ahrie: in any case, I have given you the information you need to answer the question you asked. The real problem is that you are not starting with correct bytes to begin with.  You need to fix THAT first, then you can apply what I have given you.

Comment: These questions from help vamps are soooo frustrating!!

Comment: @RemyLebeau: Hmm, i mistake took those array as PNG, better way using other method. Thank about your help remy, i take this as answered, thanks